# SQL. как получить последние записи из таблицы с джойном и условием по другой таблице

Tags: sql

Используем Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17

есть такой запрос

```
 SELECT TOP (1000) ua.[Id]
  ,ua.[UserId]
  ,a.[CreatedOn]
  ,a.[Colony]
  FROM [Lime_Mexico].[dbo].[UserAddresses] ua
  join [Lime_Mexico].[dbo].[Addresses] a on ua.[AddressId] = a.[Id]
  where ua.[AddressType] = 1
```

Выдача в скриншоте. 
Что добавить чтобы по каждому юзеру выдавалась только одна последняя запись?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте функции аналитики SQL сервера.

```
SELECT q.[Id], q.[UserId], q.[CreatedOn], q.[Colony]
FROM (
  SELECT ua.[Id], ua.[UserId], a.[CreatedOn], a.[Colony],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY ua.[UserId] 
      ORDER BY a.[CreatedOn] DESC
    ) AS rank
  FROM [UserAddresses] ua
  JOIN [Addresses] a 
  ON ua.[AddressId] = a.[Id]
  WHERE ua.[AddressType] = 1
) q
WHERE q.rank = 1
```

Вот рабочий пример на [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ffb9d/4)